# Is their any way to autoupdate AdobeAnalytics SDK in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, analytics, adobe-analytics

Is their any way to automate the update process(by run script or by any other means) of Adobe analytics library([Adobe Analytics for iOS](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services/releases/tag/v4.4.0-iOS)) whenever their is an update from Adobe instead of doing every time manually in native iOS apps.
Any suggestions is appreciated in advance

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods is the perfect solution of these questions.

Comment: @FischerCS , Can I get any reference url for this in cocoapods?

Comment: If there is no url ,you can create one using the source code by yourself. And you only need to manage the git repos in the future.